# Trying the Master/Detail of Angular2 Tutorial

Tags: angular

I followed step by step the official tutorial to learn Angular2. I allways did exactly what it indicates but I can't get the heroes list through ngFor directive. So, this my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero = HEROES;
};
```

**app.template.ts**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
</div>

<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>
    {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Browser result**

[image]

Here is the tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html
And now? What's wrong with that? Are just the first steps! Thanks for help me.

Comment: Hey! Could you create a code snippet, so we can see all the parts?

Comment: `heroes = HEROES;` instead of `hero = HEROES`

Comment: You're trying to display hero.name and hero.id in the template of a component which doesn't have a single hero, but which has an array of heroes. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And in tutorial i see `selectedHero: Hero;`

Comment: you're missing a few details, no pun intended - just reference the example a little closer - https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-2/ts/eplnkr.html

Comment: I replaced `heroes = HEROES` instead `hero = HEROES` and it got worse.

Answer (score 0):

When you do "let hero of heroes" hero is the variable that is let for you and what you iterate with. But heroes needs to be declared in your component. Is the array you refer to for iteration. It is case sensitive so the true is that you have not declared heroes, you have declared HEROES.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, the error was here:

```
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
</div>
```

The variable `hero.name` and `hero.id` was not declarated until you select a hero of the list. So be carefully with that if you follow the oficial tutorial because they say that it would have to function but is not like this until you complete the code with the selection function.